# An identity satisfied by "Differentiation"

Tags: polynomials, abstract-algebra, coalgebras

I asked [this question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381771/a-question-on-coalgebras2) but I did not received any answer. So I repeat it here:

Assume that $C$ is  a  coalgebra with comultiplication $\Delta:C \to C\otimes C$. The higher order comultiplication can be defined inductively as follows(with some abuse of notations we denote them by $\Delta$,  again):

$$\Delta:C\to C\otimes C \otimes C\\ \text{with}\\ \Delta:=(\Delta \otimes id) \circ \Delta$$....etc.

Consider the polynomial coalgebra $C=\mathbb{C}[x]$  with  [divided power structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalgebra) Then every power of the differentiation operator satisfies $$(\overbrace{T\otimes T \ldots\otimes T}^{n-times} )\circ \Delta=\Delta \circ T^{n}\\  \forall  n\in \mathbb{N}$$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381760/a-question-on-coalgebras1)

> Is there another example of an operator on polynomial coalgebra which satisfies the above equation for all natural number $n$? Is there an example of  an operator on polynomial coalgebra which satisfies the above equation for some $n>2$ but does not satisfy for $n=2$?

Comment: I do not understand your formula: $\Delta (T(X))=\Delta(1)=1\otimes 1$ while $(T\otimes T)\Delta(X)=(T\otimes T)(X\otimes 1+1\otimes X)=0$.

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli  We have to put $T^{2}(X)$  not  $T(X)$. Please read the question again.

Comment: The  identity is $(T\otimes T)\circ \Delta =\Delta \circ T^{2}$. So $T^{2}(X)=0$.

Comment: Yep sorry, I was confused by your choice of not putting powers in coproducts; I guess your formula is:$T^{\otimes n}\circ \Delta^{n-1}=\Delta^{n-1}\circ T^n$ for any $n\ge 1$, as maps from $C$ to $C^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli  yes this is what I meant.